# relationship from Table to X with foreign key properties x cannot target the primary key x because it is not compatible

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Whenever I am creating a database and feeding on startup(without migrations) It has triggered an error that says

The relationship from 'OrderProducts.Product' to 'Product' with foreign key properties {'IDProduct' : int} cannot target the primary key {'IDProduct' : Guid} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship

and I cant seem to find a way to correctly configure that the foreign keys are also primary key on this table

```cs
    public class OrderProducts
    {
  

        [ForeignKey("IDProduct")]
        public virtual Producto Product {get;set;}=
        
        [ForeignKey("IDOrder")]
        public virtual Orden Orden {get;set;}
    }
```

````cs
    public class Product
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        public Guid IDProduct { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Name cant exceed 500 chars")]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(29, 2)")]
        [Range(typeof(decimal),"0", "79228162514264337593543950335", ErrorMessage = "Price Limit between 0 - 79228162514264337593543950335")]
        public decimal Price{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ProductTypeEnum ProductType { get; set; }

      
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Name cant exceed 500 chars")]
        public string Description{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ulong Stock{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string PhotoPath{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Gender  Gender {get;set;}

        [Required]
        public TallasDeProductoEnum Talla {get;set;}
        [Required]
        public Guid Code{ get; set; }

    }```

```cs  
     public class Order
    {
        
        [Key]
        public Guid IDOrder { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ulong Qty {get;set;}

        [ForeignKey("IDClient")]
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
        //public virtual List<Product> Productos {get;set;}

        public decimal Total { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date{get;set;}

        public string IdPayment {get;set;}

        public PaymentTypeEnum PaymentType {get;set;}

        //public   List<OrdenProductos> OrderProducts  { get; set; }
         
    }
````

in AppDbContext

```cs
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<OrdenProductos> 
              ().HasKey(nameof(Producto.IDProducto),nameof(Orden.IDOrden));
       
                modelBuilder.Entity<SEOModel>().HasNoKey();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
       
           
            modelBuilder.Seed();
        }
```

what i want to do is a many to many relationship to create a database without any migration but i need to select these columns are PK and FK at the same as a kind of lookup table for orders

Comment: The foreign key reference in your table has to be the same type as the indexed field that it is referring to e.g. Guid

Comment: @ChrisBD well I am technically trying to use the field inside the Product object as my reference foreign key in fact i have got it to work on a different project but somehow it doesnt work with this since I am not doing a migration

Comment: It's complaining that `public virtual Producto Product {get;set;}=` is an `int` and not a Guid. Is the `=` in the actual code? If so try removing it.

Comment: @ChrisBDin fact it was a typo the ´=' but what I mean is that it is a Guid i mean it should infer it is a Guid, how it is deducting it is a int?

Comment: `int` tends to be a default type for numbers, especially if there's any kind of confusion. A Guid is really just a very large number of fixed size and generated in a specific way.

Comment: @ChrisBD can I specificy the column type for Entity framework I know there is an attribute but how can you define it on fluent api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> public class OrderProducts
> { 
>     [ForeignKey("IDProduct")]
>     public virtual Producto Product {get;set;} 
>     [ForeignKey("IDOrder")]
>     public virtual Orden Orden {get;set;}
> }
> public class Order
> {        
>     [Key]
>     public Guid IDOrder { get; set; }
>     ...
> }
> public class Product
> {
>     [Required]
>     [Key]
>     public Guid IDProduct { get; set; }
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> The relationship from 'OrderProducts.Product' to 'Product' with
> foreign key properties {'IDProduct' : int} cannot target the primary
> key {'IDProduct' : Guid} because it is not compatible. Configure a
> principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this
> relationship

The error message is clear, by using the Fluent API to configure the primary key, it will generate a primary key with `int` type, but in the Order and Product class, we can see the primary key is the `Guid` type, so it will show the above not compatible error.

To the this issue, you can set the foreign key data type in the OrderProducts class, like this:

```
public class OrderProducts
{
    public Guid IDProduct { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IDProduct")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public Guid IDOrder { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IDOrder")]
    public virtual Order Orden { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Liv I have done this

Comment: public class OrderProducts:IEntity
    {
        [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int OrderProductId { get; set; }
    } then in appdbcontext 
            modelBuilder.Entity<OrderProducts>().HasKey(new string[] {nameof(Order.OrderId), nameof(Product.ProductId)});